# How to download webform data to an Excel file?

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module (version 7.x-4.8), which I only enabled (I didn't change any configuration). I have 10 records in the database.

I want to download the data from Webform to an Excel file, using the typical screen to do so, as in this screenprint:

[image]

I tried using these **Export Formats**:

- **Microsoft Excel**: I can't open the download with with Microsoft Excel 2007.
- **Delimited text**: No data in the file.

I also tried using these **Download Range Options** (which didn't help either):

- Set `All submissions (10 total)`.
- Set `Submissions by number from '1' and optionally to:(blank)`.

Any suggestions about what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

Above the Download button,you can select range option from here.

[image]

Comment: @estoyausente Oh...this... I had already set All submissions (10 total). Microsoft excel 2007 cant open and I tried Delimited text. No data in the file.

Comment: I have set Submissions by number from '1' and optionally to:(blank) and It's working fine for me.

Comment: I had tried your method. Still the same problem.

Comment: strange!!! Which version you used? Did you cleared the cache? Could you provide the steps of configuration. So, we can find out the actual root cause.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform (7.x-4.8). I never change any configuration. Only enable the module.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to configure the  "Download range options"? I'm not sure but the default config is "Download element that never have been downloaded yet" or something similar.

Comment: Where is download range options?

Comment: Above the Download button. Do you have any log message in dblog, php log or any other log that you have?